# Teamcity doesnt handle failure conditions based on percentage units

Tags: teamcity, code-coverage

We're running Teamcity 8.1.5 and I am trying to get builds to fail when the percentage code coverage drops below a certain threshold.

We are printing the service messages to stdout ...

[image]

and we can see that these are picked up by the teamcity server because they appear in the Reported Statistics Values tab

[image]

But for some reason when the failure conditions checks are executed the server says that these values are not present anymore.

[image]

Thsi doesn't happen when we use one of the build statistics values of type int, only for those which take a percentage value.

Are we printing the values in the logs incorrectly? Do we need to do something differently?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In versions prior to TeamCity 9.0 the value should be a positive/negative integer. Since **TeamCity 9.0**, float values with up to 6 decimal places are also supported.